# What is "ShowWindow Lib "user32" " about?

Tags: vb.net, interop, pinvoke

I was looking over some code that another developer wrote and found this:

```
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal handle As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal handle As IntPtr) As Integer
```

What does it do and what is it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are PInvoke declarations.  They represent functions that exist in C libraries and are defined in such a way as to allow them to be called from VB.Net.  For instance, ShowWindow is a declaration of the Win32 ShowWindow function present in user32.dll.  Calling this stub will end up calling the C function.

ShowWindow: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548.aspx

This particular style of declaration is known as Dll Declare.  The more common syntax is to use DllImport and shared methods (mainly because its' compatible with C#'s implementation).  The DllDeclare syntax is in many ways a holdover from VB6 style interop.

Comment: You may also want to look at: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ShowWindow.html

Comment: I see no reason to avoid the Declare syntax unless you actually need to specify the optional parameters in the DllImport attribute.

Comment: i used to enjoy this code for hiding the window of external app, but no luck when i need to re-show it back. no wonder. :D

Answer (score 0):

These are almost certainly P/Invoke calls; i.e. a declaration that allows you to call a Windows API function, that is declared in user32.dll.